# How to decide priority to a message at application layer in VANETs

Tags: omnet++, veins

In veins there are 4 Access Categories in CCH and 4 AC's in SCH. The static mapping between priority and AC is done in `Mac1609_4::mapUserPriority()` function.

How can we decide which priority to assign to a *message(beacon-periodic/emergency-event/wsa-service)* at application layer? 
Is there a standard that defines this priority assignment?. 
In the example that comes in veins, both beacon and WSM messages are assigned with a priority of 7.

I have seen some papers where they assign priority based on contents of the message. For a quick simulation, is it fine if we assign priorities like *beacon* (6), *emergency* (7) and *wsa* (5) or lower.  Should Emergency messages given more priority than beacon messages?  If we assign priorities like this, Are we actually using 4 AC queues here in this case?

Comment: Is this question answered?

Comment: yes. Thanks, Julian. I don't see a way to mark it as answered for this question.

Comment: There should be gray check-mark next to answer which will become green, if you click it..

Comment: done. Accepted the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AC of a `WaveShortMessage` is determined by setting its `userPriority` value (see [WaveShortMessage](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage.msg#L31) and [BaseWaveApplLayer](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc#L170)).